# TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

I will only publish the part of the code that gives me errors.

When I run the bot it takes about 3 seconds and the bot crashes with the error that I have placed below.

In case it helps something to fix the error, the bot is a ticket bot to support users, it consists of reacting to an emoji and the bot creates a room with permissions and a message, you can close the ticket and the room is removed.

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client();

const config = require('./config.json');
var userTickets = new Map();

client.login(config.token);

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(client.user.username + " has logged in.");

    client.user.setPresence( {
        status: "online",
        game: {
            name: "Tickets",
            type: "WATCHING"
        }
    })
});

// code

client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.author.bot) {
        if(message.embeds.length === 1 && message.embeds[0].description.startsWith('Reacc')) {
            message.react(idemoji1).then( () => message.react(idemoji2)).then( () =>  message.react(idemoji3))
            .then(msgReaction => console.log('reacted'))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
        if(message.embeds.length === 1 && message.embeds[0].description == '¡Gracias por crear el ticket!\nEl soporte se pondrá en contacto contigo lo antes posible.\n\nPor favor, responde las preguntas que se te hacen a continuación para poder date el mejor soporte.\n\n Si no escribes nada, el ticket se cerrará en 2 horas.\n\nPara cerrar este ticket reacciona a ') {
            message.react(emoji5)
            .then(reaction => console.log("A reaccionado con " + reaction.emoji.name))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    };
```

Console error:

```
C:\Users\nilma\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord-Ticket-Psyco\ticketbot-reaction.js:43
        if(message.embeds.length === 1 && message.embeds[0].description.startsWith('Reacc')) {
                                                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nilma\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord-Ticket-Psyco\ticketbot-reaction.js:43:73)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\nilma\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord-Ticket-Psyco\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\nilma\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord-Ticket-Psyco\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\nilma\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord-Ticket-Psyco\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\nilma\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord-Ticket-Psyco\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\nilma\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord-Ticket-Psyco\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\nilma\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord-Ticket-Psyco\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Comment: It seems like there's no embed description: whty don't you just add a check before calling the `startsWith` method? something like `message.embeds[0].description && message.embeds[0].description.startsWith(...)`

Comment: If I do what you told me, I will get the following error. If you need me to show more code to help me, you just have to ask me: D

error:

`C:\Users\nilma\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord-Ticket-Psyco\ticketbot-reaction.js:43
        if(message.embeds[0].description && message.embeds[0].description.startsWith('Reacc')) {`

Comment: You didn't post the error... I mean, you posted the part of the file where it happens, but not the description or the point where it happens. Also, you deleted the part where you check for the length of the `.embeds` array, you should add that back